# what tables uses wp_get_post_terms

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have a (uncommented) legacy code that is using wp_get_post_terms function, and always returns WP_Error (Invalid Taxonomy).
The calling of the function is:

```
$location = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, "location");
```

I had been inspecting the database, and the first conclusion is that in the table `wp_term_taxonomy` there are many entries with "location" into `taxonomy` field.
So I have trhee questions: Why this? How this function relates the post_id with the taxonomy? and the last one... what tables uses wp_get_post_terms?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at the official documentation of [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/). Also check your list of post tags.

Comment: Thanks @hcheung. But I had been reading this doc, and there is nothing about the tables of the database that the function uses. And I have been digging in the batabase all the tables that could be related: wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms, wp_term_relationships. But I found nothing that links post_id with the taxonomy.

Comment: Anything related to terms, it would be under `WP_Term_Query()` class where you can find out how the database is accessed. [This article](https://www.shawnhooper.ca/2015/10/cleaning-up-unused-terms-in-wordpress-database-in-mysql/) might also help you to solve the orphaned taxonomy and also understand the interrelationship between the database tables.